# GCP CloudSql Connection limit from Dataflow Job/compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-sql

I have a dataflow job that is connecting to cloudsql and persisting some data.
On average I have about 75 active connections (a few spikes to just over 100 connections once in a while). I was therefore wondering if there is a maximum number of connections. The documentation doesn't seem to indicate. (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip)

Backstory and for some context: I am getting an error with one of my jobs, it seems to just lock randomly and stops persisting data:

```
Operation ongoing in step X for at least 305h20m00s without outputting or completing in state start
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst (LinkedBlockingDeque.java:590)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject (GenericObjectPool.java:425)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject (GenericObjectPool.java:346)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection (PoolingDataSource.java:134)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection (BasicDataSource.java:809)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DataSourceConnectionFactory.createConnection (DataSourceConnectionFactory.java:83)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject (PoolableConnectionFactory.java:355)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create (GenericObjectPool.java:874)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject (GenericObjectPool.java:417)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject (GenericObjectPool.java:346)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection (PoolingDataSource.java:134)
at x.io.jobs.common.mysql.function.MySqlReadAllFn.setup (MySqlReadAllFn.java:57)
at x.io.jobs.tracer.function.ReadAggTraceStatusByIdFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeSetup (Unknown Source)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.deserializeCopy (DoFnInstanceManagers.java:83)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.get (DoFnInstanceManagers.java:75)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.reallyStartBundle (SimpleParDoFn.java:296)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement (SimpleParDoFn.java:326)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process (ParDoOperation.java:44)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process (OutputReceiver.java:49)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output (GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:185)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue (GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:108)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1 (ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a connection limit for Cloud SQL, which can be changed by setting the `max_connections` flag on an instance. There's more info on setting and viewing the value of database flags on an instance here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags